# cannot be applied to operands of type string and string

Tags: c#

i got error when i try to make textbox red if number below 18

can you helping me with that ?

i dont know how to fix the problem

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                double numt = 18;
                if (textBox1.Text <= numt)   ////error here
                {

                    textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red; 
                }
            else
            {
                textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
```

Comment: Please don't add the [visual-studio] tag unless your question is actually about the tool itself. Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: its work but if i clear input to enter another number i got "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: _"if i clear input to enter another number i got "Input string was not in a correct format.""_ -- that's a completely different issue, but you can find the answer exactly the same way you _should_ have found the answer to this one: just search Stack Overflow (or the web!) for the exact text of the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Convert   **`textBox1.Text`** to dobule to make the comparison.

```
   if (Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) <= numt)
```

Comment: its work but if i clear input to enter another number i got "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @NAWAFWABS in that case check if it has value

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `textBox1.Text` to a `double` with `double.Parse(...)`. You can't "directly" compare strings and doubles because it could result in complete nonsense operations like

```
if ("dog" <= 18)
{
   // Do whatever
}
else if ("chair" > 2.3)
{
   // ...
}
```

Clearly, this is complete nonsense. While *you* may know that `textBox1.Text` will contain a number, the compiler *doesn't* know that - the main point is that you could, in principle, have a situation like that.

Incidentally, don't just blindly trust the user to do the right thing. Consider what will happen if the user puts in something *other* than an integer, and validate it before you try to use it. So really, you *don't* know that this will result in something sensible - for all you know the user could type something like "dog" or "chair" in the text box, and then you'd have a clearly nonsensical situation like we have above.